# CUDA:how to call a host function from a global function

Tags: cuda

```
1 #include<stdlib.h>
  2 #include<stdio.h>
  3 #include"cuda.h"
  4 __global__ void malloctest()
  5 {
  6         char * ptr=(char *)malloc(123);
  7         printf("thread %d got a pointer:%p\n",threadIdx.x,ptr);
  8         free(ptr);
  9 }
 10 int main()
 11 {
 12         cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize,128*1024*1024);
 13         malloctest<<<1,5>>>();
 14         cudaDeviceSynchronize();
 15         return 0;
 16 }



nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
malloctest.cu(6) (col. 9): error: calling a __host__ function("malloc") from a __global__ function("malloctest") is not allowed

malloctest.cu(7): error: calling a __host__ function("printf") from a __global__ function("malloctest") is not allowed

malloctest.cu(8): error: calling a __host__ function("free") from a __global__ function("malloctest") is not allowed
```

how to make it available? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e,i find the answer,i should change the gpu arch to 3.0

```
nvcc malloctest.cu -o 1 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"
```